# How can I insert a XML file in a XHTML page <textarea> using JSP?

Tags: xml, jsp, xhtml, jstl

How can I include a XML file as content in a textarea element in a XHTML document? It will cause validation errors if the special characters are not escaped.

Is there an easy way in JSP to escape special characters before they are inserted using the include directive, like using the JSTL?

Example code:

```
    <div>
        <textarea name="content" rows="20" cols="80"><%@ include file="example.xml" %></textarea>
    </div>
```

This will look fine in a browser, but XHTML validation will fail because the embedded file starts another XML declaration.

Comment: It will only "look fine" in the browser if the browser recovers from the error and the XML file doesn't include the string `</textarea>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "official" JSTL way of doing this is as follows:

```
<c:import url="example.xml" var="xmlContent"/>

<textarea><c:out value="${xmlContent}" escapeXml="true"/></textarea>
```

The `escapeXml` attribute defaults to true anyway, but it's probably wise to specify it here, for reasons of documentation.

Comment: You probably means it defaults to `true`...?

Comment: s/defaults to false/defaults to true. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: Oops, sorry yes, I thought "true" and typed "false".

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to embed your `<%@ include %>` within a `<![CDATA[...]]>` so it is considered as plain text rather than XML parts. You can read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp) to get a bit more insight on what CDATA is for.

Comment: That only works if the document is served with an XML content type (such as application/xhtml+xml) most uses of XHTML serve it as text/html so CDATA markers are ignored.